# How do you call this type of linear regression?

Tags: regression

How do you call a regression such as :

$ Y_{i} = \alpha _{i}+ \beta _{i} \times X_{i}$ where $\beta _{i}$ is changing for each $_{i}$ ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What does $i$ index? Is it datapoints, or variables/dimensions?

Comment: This is single variate linear regression without the error term.

Comment: @user20160, it is datapoints.

Comment: @chris  thanks for your help ! When looking online for "single variate linear regression" I can find some documentation about it, but not so many, do you if there would be a different name for this ?

Comment: Time dependent regression

Comment: As formulated it's just an equation.

Comment: @chris : i know it's just an equation, i'm trying to put some words on it in order to find a methodology to implement in r ....

Comment: If you only have one y for each $i$ the system of equations won't be identifiable unless you relate the coefficients over time.